# Find the second derivative of $y=\left(1-2\sqrt{x}\right)^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the second derivative of $$y=\left(1-2\sqrt{x}\right)^3$$ Let's find the first derivative: $$y'=3(1-2\sqrt{x})^2(1-2\sqrt{x})'=3\left(0-2\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)(1-2\sqrt{x})^2=-3\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}(1-2\sqrt{x})^2$$ The second derivative of a function is the derivative of the derivative of that function, so $$y''=\left(-3\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}(1-2\sqrt{x})^2\right)'=-3\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot(1-2\sqrt{x})^2\right)'=-3T$$ I am really having troubles with finding that derivative as I get confused (too many things going on). $$T=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)'(1-2\sqrt{x})^2+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left((1-2\sqrt{x})^2\right)'=\\-\dfrac12x^{-\frac32}(1-4\sqrt{x}+4x)-\dfrac{2}{x}(1-2\sqrt{x})$$ Is there an easier approach?

Comment: I think it's worth getting used to this approach and practicing it for eventual mastery (keeping track of all the things going on is one of the skills we want to strengthen in mathematics). That being said, another approach is to multiply out the expression (either the cube in $y$ itself, or the square in $y'$) and then every term is just a power of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are correct.  After simplification, the result is $$y'' = \frac{3(1-4x)}{2x^{3/2}}.$$

A simpler approach that works in this case is to expand the cube:

$$y = (1 - 2x^{1/2})^3 = 1 - 6x^{1/2} + 12x - 8x^{3/2}.$$  Then no product or chain rule is required:

$$y' = -3x^{-1/2} + 12 - 12x^{1/2},$$

and

$$y'' = \frac{3}{2}x^{-3/2} - 6x^{-1/2}.$$